# ASP.NET MVC button not firing navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, navigation

I am learning ASP.NET MVC newly. I am trying to setup a navigation between screen as below

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{       
    public ActionResult Welcome(string newId)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to my shop.";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Welcome.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h1>The shoppee</h1>    
    <input type="button" title="Cart" value="Shop Items" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("SelectItems", "Cart") %>'" />
}
```

I have built a new CartController with SelectItems.cshtml. I have added them to routeconfig.cs. But the button above is not firing at all. I am able to manually navigate to the url using

```
http://localhost:portnumber/Cart/SelectItems
```

Comment: Simply remove the `% >` at the end of the url. Also, Why do you need to put that button inside a form?

Comment: I know its going to be lame. But didn't expect it to be this lame. Thanks mate. The form is not required as it is only a redirect, it was an attempt to make it work.

Comment: Be far easier to use a link (`@Html.ActionLink(...)`) and style it as a button